# combining session with an another API using slick

Tags: scala, slick, scalaz

`moduel1` has a

```
def save(model: MyModel) : Future[\/[Errs, MyModel] ] = async{
  db.withSession{
  ......
  }
}
```

`module1` has a REST endpoint which will let users persist `MyModel` coming in from the caller (web app in this case) so save() will have to work as an independent endpoint/API. No issues here.

now `module2` is creating a new API which will have to "combine" above `save()` with other `db` operation and run those two operations in a single [transation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0-M3/connection.html#transactions). Note these two `modules` are part of a single project so sharing same database and schema. `module2` is bringing in `module1` as a sbt dependency.

```
def module2Save(model2 : Module2Model) : Future[\/[Err, Module2Model]] = async {
    db.withTransaction {
      val res = module1.save(model2.dataForModel1)
      //after res do other db operation 
      .....
    }
}
```

as we know we **must** create a session/transaction inside a future [not outside](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0-M3/connection.html#automatically-closing-session-scope) - `def module2Save` violates that when calling `module1.save()` hence doesn't function right way (as expected and no surprise there).

Question is : Is it even possible to combine running `module1`'s `save()` and `module2`'s `module2Save` into a single slick transaction especially when `module1.save()` is operating as a standalone API service endpoints in `module1` inside a [Future](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$) ?

What's the other way to achieve database [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29) for `module2.module2Save()` which will have to fail or succeed it's transaction based on `module1.save()` ?

Comment: Check out Slick 3.0 which provides a completely new API to solve problems like this one.

Comment: @szeiger : thanks. I have seen bits and pieces of new API. unfortunately it'll take some time for us to plan migration to Slick 3.0 - given Slick 3.0 APIs are quite different than older versions.